# How to pass data from async task of activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

In activity i am using async task to get data from web service and after parsing how to send data from activity to fragment,i have tried using bundle but no luck.If it is directly from activity then bundle works fine [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)
but how to pass data from async task from activity to fragment 
here is my async task

```
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetQuotes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        System.out.println(jsonStr);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                pages = jsonObj.optJSONArray(TAG_PAGES);

                System.out.println(pages);
                JSONObject c = pages.getJSONObject(0);
                caption0 = c.getString(TAG_CAPTION);     
                quote0 = c.getString(TAG_QUOTE);
                System.out.println("obj1" + caption0 + quote0);

                JSONObject c1 = pages.getJSONObject(1);
                caption1 = c1.getString(TAG_CAPTION);
                quote1 = c1.getString(TAG_QUOTE);
                System.out.println("obj2" + caption1 + quote1);

                JSONObject c2 = pages.getJSONObject(0);
                caption2 = c2.getString(TAG_CAPTION);
                quote2 = c2.getString(TAG_QUOTE);
                System.out.println("obj3" + caption2 + quote2);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog

    }

}
```

Comment: add intent code in onPostExecute of your asynchtask..

Comment: Could you please have a look on my activity http://pastebin.com/rd8tuz6U

Comment: ok now explain me in detail with your class name what you want to achieve.

Comment: where have you define the "GetQuotes " class ?

Comment: I want to pass data  from activity to samplefragment1

Comment: caption0 = c.getString(TAG_CAPTION);     
                quote0 = c.getString(TAG_QUOTE);

Comment: Why don't you use static variable? Then you don't need to send any data in your fragment. Just need to call that.

Comment: Yes i have tried then getting null value for that variable

Comment: Pass it using fragment contructor

Answer (score 2):

Pass your data through bundle
:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("CAPTION", caption0);
bundle.putString("QUOTE", quote0);
data.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, fragmentName)
                    .commit();
```

And In fragment class retrieve data from bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String caption0 = bundle.getString("CAPTION");
String quote0 = bundle.getString("QUOTE");
```

Comment: In activity bundle.putString("CAPTION", caption0); getting null pointer exception as you seen caption0 value assigning in async task not in activity

Comment: where did you create the bundle?? create bundle object in onPostExecute() method.